# How to include the Composer's autoload if it's outside of my web server root?

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I am supposed to do this:

```
require_once  'vendor/autoload.php';
```

But Composer's vendor folder has been installed in the home directory of my Ubuntu machine.

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
```

How am I supposed to require that file if it's outside the web server directory?

I tried `require_once  $HOME.'/vendor/autoload.php';` but didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: I realised that Composer was installed in the ROOT home directory, this is why my web server couldn't access it. Installing it in the user home directory solved it.**

Comment: Use the full path, or `../` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried  $HOME.'/vendor/autoload.php' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is `$HOME`'s value? That's not a standard PHP var.

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be wrong. Got that from another post.

Comment: consider fixing your composer installation, if you dont have an imperative reason to have the `vendor` folder remote from the project's root.

Comment: Please provide the relevant file system structure and, especially, the web server configuration settings for the virtual host in question. Personally, I'm suspecting a restriction imposed by your web server configuration (as well).

Comment: Hi there,  I realised that Composer was installed in the ROOT home directory, this is why my web server couldn't access it. Installing it in the user home directory solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear. Remember that the `vendor` folder should not reside in the document root. And to access it only by applying a relative path (with `../vendor/autoload.php`, or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$_SERVER['HOME']` - Read more about `$_SERVER` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Other Options:

1. Full path to the file
2. Relative path to the file

Comment: that's great when the library only has a SAPI runtime context, but most likely would fail if some part of it is meant for cli-type applications.

Comment: Hi there,  I realised that Composer was installed in the ROOT home directory, this is why my web server couldn't access it. Installing it in the user home directory solved it.